# Consistency timeouts in Commanded after deployment

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, cqrs, event-sourcing, commanded

In an event sourced application built with Commanded and Phoenix we get a `consistency_timeout` during the processing of commands after deployment to our production environment (Heroku).

Here is the log output:

```
[debug] Processing with Web.CountryController.select_country_for_mission/2
[info] Invoicing.Commands.SelectCountryForMission dispatch start
[debug] Locating aggregate process for `Invoicing.Mission` with UUID "mission-23"
[debug] Invoicing.Mission<mission-23@4> executing command: %Invoicing.Commands.SelectCountryForMission{mission_id: "23", country_id: "42"}
[debug] Appended 1 event(s) to stream "mission-23"
[info] Invoicing.Commands.SelectCountryForMission succeeded in 180ms
[warn] Consistency timeout waiting for aggregate "mission-23" at version 5
```

If I submit the form twice one of the commands is processed successfully - but the read model is still not updated. After some minutes the problem vanishes on production. On my machine the problem doesn't seem to vanish.

The application uses the event store of commanded with Ecto projections.

Versions:

- Commanded 0.17.0
- commanded_ecto_projections 0.7.1
- commanded_eventstore_adapter 0.4.0
- eventstore 0.14.0
- Erlang 20.3.2
- Elixir 1.6.5
- Phoenix 1.3.4

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Heroku deployments but are you running multiple nodes, and if so how have you configured Commanded and Event Store libraries?

It might be easier to debug the issue via [Commanded's Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/commanded/Lobby).